# "It is an advantage learning a foreign language". -> It is an advantage to learn...? (infinitive or -ing)

Tags: grammar, gerund-vs-infinitive

I've come across the following sentence in an article which provides businessmen with advice on how to improve their career prospects.

"It is an advantage learning a foreign language."

I think the sentence is wrong and it should be "It is an advantage to learn a foreign language." (or better: It can be an advantage to learn a foreign language.)

Do you agree and can you tell me why the sentence is wrong (or why it is not)?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: The Cambridge Dictionary lists only example sentences with the to-infinitve, such as: 
 [ + to infinitive ] It would be to your advantage **to agree** to his demands.
For a goalkeeper, it's a great advantage **to have** big hands.

Apart from that, I tried to consult different corpora and entered different terms, for example "it is an advantage working" vs. "it is an advantage to work" or "it is an advantage doing" vs. "it is an advantage to do" and the results differed significantly. There were many results using the "to-infinitive" and only few results with a gerund form.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain _why_ you think the gerund construction is wrong. (Both are actually fine and so are both “Learning a foreign language is an advantage” and “To learn a foreign language is an advantage”.)

Comment: I'm not educated like some of these folks, but, I agree with you. If the sentence you presented is not technically wrong, it sounds awkward to a native ear.

Comment: I would think that "the act" of 'learning' would be "advantageous", and "It is an advantage to **know** a foreign language."

Comment: The sentence was not written by a competent English writer. *Knowing* a foreign language *is* an advantage; *learning* a foreign language *gives* you an advantage.

Answer (score -1):

**The short answer : It depends on the context.** 
If the context is one in which the very 'act' of learning foreign languages is *generally* being encouraged, then the gerund form is correct. 
If the context is one of a *specific* case or a person being encouraged to learn, the infinitive form is correct. 
Imagine the two situations, and check for yourself !